# Custom Taxonomy Tags and Category using same slug

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I seem to had hit a problem with using the same 'slug' => 'publications', for `register_taxonomy` _category and _tag. It seems only the last call `register_taxonomy('publications_tag',` is able to use the slug. Where as the previous call `register_taxonomy('publications_category',` renders a 404.

How can I use the same slug for category and tag, which I assume would then use my taxonomy-{post-type_.php template?

// Custom Post Type:

```
register_post_type( 'publications', $args );

    $args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Publication', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Publications', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail',
        'excerpt',
        'revisions',
        'author',
        'post-formats',
        //'comments',
        'page-attributes'
        ),
    'taxonomies'            => array(
        'publications_category',
        'publications_tag'
        ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 20,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-align-left',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => 'publications',
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'show_in_rest'          => true,
    'rewrite'                           => array(
    //  'slug' => 'publications',
        'with_front' => false
        ),
);
```

// Categorys:

```
register_taxonomy('publications_category', 'publications', array (
    'labels' => array (
    //
    ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'publications',
            'with_front' => false ),
        'public' => true
        )
);
```

// Tags:

```
register_taxonomy('publications_tag','publications', array(
    'labels' => array (
    //
    ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'publications',
            'with_front' => false ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. WordPress determines what type of content you're querying by looking at slugs, and you cannot have two different types (i.e. two separate taxonomies) that use the exact same slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working by adding **/tag** or **/category** for the rewrite slug, rather then `publications` or `publications/%publications_tag%`. I initally thought both taxonomy types could live in the parent post-type and wordpress would figure the rest out.

Tags:

  `'rewrite' => array(
  'slug' => 'publication/tag',
  'with_front' => false ),`

Looks like: `domain.test/publications/tag/example-tag/` and use's the `axonomy-publications_tag.php` file.

Category:

  `'rewrite' => array(
  'slug' => 'publication/category',
  'with_front' => false ),`

Looks like: `domain.test/publications/category/example-category/` and use's the `axonomy-publications_category.php` file.